# why createStore is strikethrough?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

[image]

Im trying to do a project with react and redux but the state doesn't work. I think it is beacause when I initialize the store, the method createStore appears crossed out, as seen in the image.

How can i fix that?

Im alredy install redux and react-redux with npm.

The editor es VScode

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981

Comment: It's likely to be a linting warning. Please hover over it to see the message.

Answer (score -1):

createStore is deprecated use configureStore from the @reduxjs/toolkit package instead.